# Node.js Error: Cannot find module (local file)

Tags: node.js, docker

---

I am following Node.js's ["Intro to Docker" tutorial](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) and, when I run `npm start`, the project works. When I run `docker run (options)`, the build is generated, but I'll find the error below in the logs. The project is bare-bones, simple, and straight-forward, I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I've gotten a very similar error in production earlier (to Heroku, without Docker), where local runs look good and live deploys get a similar error.

I'm not sure if I'm using something outdated, but I updated npm, docker, and am not sure what else could be.

Any help is appreciated!

---

**Error:**

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969

throw err;

^


Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/server.js'

at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)

at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)

at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)

at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {

code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

requireStack: []

}
```

**Directory:**

[image]

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "SampleProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js on Docker",
  "author": "First Last <first.last@example.com>",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dock": "docker run -p 1234:1234 -d <My>/<Info>"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-util-is": "^1.0.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
    # I'm using Node.js -> Import it's image
FROM node:12

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./


RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Run on port 1234
EXPOSE 1234


CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

**server.js**

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');

// Constants
const PORT = 1234;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

// App
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

**Run:**

```
npm run dock
```

**Note:**

I've also cleaned out the project by running the following:

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install && npm start
```

---

**RESOLVED:**

---

**Dockerfile**

```
    # I'm using Node.js -> Import it's image
FROM node:12

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./


RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# * BEGIN SOLUTION *
# Bundle app source    
COPY . .
# *  END SOLUTION  *

# Run on port 1234
EXPOSE 1234


CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Comment: I think you are only copying package*.json files...you need to also copy the project files like `app.js` inside Docker.

Comment: @Rash I updated the dockerfile to contain `COPY . .` as per @abestrad 's response. I believe that should cover the same territory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the following important part, should be placed after you have `RUN npm install`:

To bundle your app's source code inside the docker image, use the COPY instruction:

```
# Bundle app source
COPY . .
```

And to force the execution of each step in the Dockerfile,

```
docker build --no-cache
```

Comment: I  tried this, didn't seem to change the outcome, I updated the Dockerfile

Comment: Try this time to build with `--no-cache` to force the execution of each step/instruction in the Dockerfile.

Comment: I'm not sure if this resolved the problem. After build & run, the process marks as "Running" (a good sign), but when I open it in a browser (from the Docker dashboard), there is no response. In an `npm start` run, there is a "Hello World" response.

Comment: That's your hello world,   `res.send('Hello World');`

Comment: I'm going to add the --no-cache to the answer for the benefit of future readers,